# ASP.NET MVC - Route to a single page dynamically

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project. Customer wants to show 'Change is in progress' page to the users during the deployment. **We want to redirect all calls to the site , to another MVC page. Once deployment is done, the  site will work as expected( i,e.Change is in progress' page won't show up)** .

These are the options I was thinking.  I have a gut feeling that this should not take much efforts to implement but I have yet to find the right solution. Please help.

1. During deployment , configure IIS to show static file (Don't like this because this is a manual process)
2. Change default route dynamically : This is also not preferred because I am not changing other valid routes.

Is there a way to ignore all routes and make the 'change is in progress' page in default route?

Answer (score 0):

What we usually do in such situations is, we create another web site in IIS with the same configuration (hostname, IP address, etc). But this site has only a static page that shows the relevant message.

So once we start the deployment, we will stop the current site and start this maintenance site. Then all the users who try to enter the original site will show the maintenance page without any disruption.

After the deployment is completed, simply stop the maintenance site and start the original site.